# Why configuring width of Frame shows differences from Label's?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, frame

(windows 7, python 2.7.3)

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
Frame(root, width=20, height=20, bg='red').pack(expand=NO, fill=None, side=LEFT)
Label(root, width=20, height=20, bg='black').pack(expand=NO, fill=None, side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

And the result is like this:

[image]

I set same width and height to the Frame and Label, but they show different size. What's more, the Label is even not a square.Please explain it for me, and show me the way to make them same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

20 is the same as 20, but 20 meters is not the same as 20 kilometers.

**Long answer:**

The result you got is not as weird as you may think because the `width` and `height` options of `Tkinter.Frame()` are measured in terms of **pixels** whereas in `Tkinter.Label()`:

- `width`: defines the width of the label in **characters**
- `height`: defines the height of the label in **lines**

[Reference.](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/label.html)

Answer (score 1):

As I know Label is used for text. Label() definition and Frame() might work differently for width and height parameters, correct me if am wrong.

example:
change width and height inside Label() to 1. you will see space for one character filled with black color in tk window.

like

`Label(root, width=1, height=1, bg='black').pack(expand=NO, fill=None, side=LEFT)`